# Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to Clamp but I've already set that

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, texture-mapping

I'm now writing a game on **WP7** using **XNA Framework 4.0**.

There are some pictures that needs to be tiled.

So I set the `SamplerState[0]` to `LinearWrap` before rendering these pictures and I switch it back to `LinearClamp` once done.

However, the game still throws exceptions when it has finished all the tiled pictures and is about to create a `VertexBuffer` for the first non-tiled (i.e. not wrapped) picture.

I've added a breakpoint at that line and has confirmed that GraphicsDevice's `Samplerstates[0]` is `LinearClamp`. All other 15 SamplerStates are `LinearWrap` but I'm not using any multi-texture features so I don't think it's the reason. (frankly, I don't even know how to use multi-texture in XNA, maybe `DualTextureEffect`?)

BTW, I've desperately set all 16 samplers to `LinearClamp`, but the problem still occurs.

Anyone has encountered similar problems or has any solution?

Comment: In addition to the above, can you post a snippet of the code that's responsible for drawing the tiled images?

Comment: @Blau: A NotSupportedException with message of: XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two.

Comment: @ColeCampbell: Sorry i don't have the code now. But I do have set up the SamplerState[0] to LinearClamp.

Comment: Why don't use texture with power of two size? go to the content project, select the texture, open de processor, set resize to power of two to true...

Comment: @Blau: will try that. I thought it would cause some quality loss though. But if it's acceptable that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

@Blau had it in his comment. 
Simply select the images you're using, open the properties window, expand Content Processor, and switch "Resize to a power of two" to true.